# How to terminate a batch when an error occurs

Tags: batch-operations

I've read this: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/batch_set/6 and through the source code, but I cannot see how a batch operation can flag that an error has occurred to show the error message.

I can set `$context['finished'] = 1.0;` to end the batch, but I cannot see how to set `$current_set['success']` to FALSE to abort the batch and show the error message to the user.

How is this done? Is there a good example somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

To set `$current_set['success']` to `FALSE`, you can use the following code.

```
$current_set = &_batch_current_set();
$current_set['success'] = FALSE;
```

To set the messages to show to the users, you can use the following code.

```
$batch_context['results'][] = 'The error to be shown to the user';
$batch_context['finished'] = 1.0;
```

`$batch_context` is the last argument passed to the operation callback.

The "finished" callback receives `$current_set['success']`, and `$batch_context['results']` respectively as first, and second argument. It can show the errors to the users using `drupal_set_message()`.

#### References

- [_batch_process()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!batch.inc/function/_batch_process/6)
- [_batch_finished()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!batch.inc/function/_batch_finished/6)